# make anchorpane resizable with size of screen

Tags: javafx, fxml

How to bind an `AnchorPane` to the size of the screen?

When I run my code it shows me that:

[image]

but when the main stage fit the screen the `AnchorPane` still has the same size.

[image]

here is my fxml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sanad.Entry_Page">
   <children>
      <Pane blendMode="RED" layoutX="563.0" layoutY="9.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="746.0" prefWidth="447.0">
         <padding>
            <Insets top="10.0" />
         </padding>
         <children>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5720620842572062" layoutX="-56.0" layoutY="-1.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="741.0" prefWidth="508.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="751.0" prefWidth="286.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="formnumer_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="sectornumber_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="fathername_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="fatherborn_year" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="fatherborn_month" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="fatherborn_day" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="fathercurrentjob" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="fatherprevjob" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="179.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="mothername_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="mother_curr_job" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="motherborn_day" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="motherborn_year" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="mother_prev_job" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="312.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="motherborn_month" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="homepartner_num" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_year" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="382.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_month" layoutX="88.0" layoutY="382.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_day" layoutX="163.0" layoutY="382.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_name" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="416.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" />
                        <CheckBox fx:id="homepartner_gender1" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="456.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="ذكر">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox fx:id="homepartner_gender2" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="456.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="أنثى">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <Label fx:id="current_cityaa" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="490.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="المحافظة">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="current_city" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="490.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
                        <Label fx:id="current_cityaa1" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="530.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="الحي">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="current_suberb" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="530.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="prev_suberb" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="615.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
                        <Label fx:id="current_cityaa11" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="615.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="الحي">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="current_cityaa2" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="575.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="المحافظة">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="prev_city" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="575.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label fx:id="formnumber" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="14.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="رقم الاستمارة" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="sectornumber" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="48.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="رقم القطاع" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="fathername" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="82.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="اسم الأب" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="fatherborn" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="112.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="المواليد" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="currentjob" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="142.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل الحالي" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="previousjob" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="172.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل السابق" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="fatherborn1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="244.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="المواليد" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="currentjob1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="278.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل الحالي" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="fathername1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="208.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="اسم الأم" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="previousjob1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="307.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل السابق" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="homepartner_sex" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="451.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="الجنس" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="homepartner_name" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="414.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="الاسم" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="partner_born" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="378.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="الميلاد" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="home_partner" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="341.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="عدد المستضافين" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="50.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="485.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="السكن الحالي">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="570.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="السكن الحالي">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.4845360824742268" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="8.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="741.0" prefWidth="487.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="327.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Try to take off preferred width and height for the AnchorPane. If possible, it will resize to those specs.

Comment: I don't fully understand, do you want the anchor pane to fill the entire window, or the window to match the screen size, or the anchor pane's size to match the screen regardless of window size? From your picture, stuff looks ok to me

Comment: He is trying to get the Panes to resize when the program is in fullscreen mode. I'm not sure how to do that. I've been fiddling with it and nothing I've done is working. Someone else who has more experience in this can help you though.

Comment: Which `AnchorPane` are you talking about. The root should be resized to the size of the `Scene`. Everything else doesn't resize, since no anchors are used. Also even if they were used, the children of the `Pane` would not be resized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using this property of AnchorPane:

```
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor
AnchorPane.leftAnchor
AnchorPane.rightAnchor
AnchorPane.topAnchor
```

But you need to decide what part of a scene will change and what is not. The width of the fixed part fix with prefWidth. Сhanging part fix with AnchorPane.leftAnchor or AnchorPane.rightAnchor given the size of the fixed part.

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sanad.Entry_Page">
   <children>
      <Accordion prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 3">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="200.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <LineChart AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try do something with this fxml, but i think that is bad created. You should rebuild everything. For right site is better to use GridPane not AnchorPane and put all elements in grid.
I created HBox in this hobx I put two AnchorPane, then each AnchorPane i put Your SplitPane. After this you must connect each SplitPane with right and left edge of AnchorPane like this:

```
  <SplitPane AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
```

Here is this fxml:
Use SceneBuilder to preview how it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="786.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
              <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.4845360824742268" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="741.0" prefWidth="487.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                  <items>
                      <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="327.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  </items>
              </SplitPane>
      </children>
   </AnchorPane>
   <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
                <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5720620842572062" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="741.0" prefWidth="508.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                    <items>
                        <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT">
                            <children>
                                <TextField fx:id="formnumer_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="43.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="sectornumber_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="43.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="fathername_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="43.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="fatherborn_year" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="226.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="fatherborn_month" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="226.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="fatherborn_day" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="226.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="fathercurrentjob" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="fatherprevjob" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="179.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="mothername_field" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="mother_curr_job" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="motherborn_day" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="73.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="motherborn_year" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="mother_prev_job" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="312.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="motherborn_month" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="249.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" />
                                <TextField fx:id="homepartner_num" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_year" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="382.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_month" layoutX="88.0" layoutY="382.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_day" layoutX="163.0" layoutY="382.0" />
                                <ComboBox fx:id="homepartner_name" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="416.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="72.0" />
                                <CheckBox fx:id="homepartner_gender1" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="456.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="ذكر">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox fx:id="homepartner_gender2" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="456.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="أنثى">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <Label fx:id="current_cityaa" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="490.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="المحافظة" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="74.0">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <TextField fx:id="current_city" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="490.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" />
                                <Label fx:id="current_cityaa1" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="530.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="الحي" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="74.0">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <TextField fx:id="current_suberb" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="530.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" />
                                <TextField fx:id="prev_suberb" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="615.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" />
                                <Label fx:id="current_cityaa11" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="615.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="الحي" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="71.0">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="current_cityaa2" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="575.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="المحافظة" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="71.0">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <TextField fx:id="prev_city" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="575.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" />
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                            <children>
                                <Label fx:id="formnumber" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="14.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="رقم الاستمارة" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="sectornumber" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="48.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="رقم القطاع" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="fathername" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="82.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="اسم الأب" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="fatherborn" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="112.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="المواليد" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="currentjob" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="142.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل الحالي" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="previousjob" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="172.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل السابق" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="fatherborn1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="244.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="المواليد" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="currentjob1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="278.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل الحالي" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="fathername1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="208.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="اسم الأم" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="previousjob1" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="307.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="العمل السابق" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="homepartner_sex" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="451.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="الجنس" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="homepartner_name" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="414.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="الاسم" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="partner_born" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="378.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="الميلاد" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="home_partner" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="341.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="عدد المستضافين" textAlignment="RIGHT" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </Label>
                                <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="485.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="السكن الحالي">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="570.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="السكن الحالي">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                </SplitPane>
              <Pane blendMode="RED" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="-Infinity" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                  <padding>
                      <Insets top="10.0" />
                  </padding>
              </Pane>
      </children>
   </AnchorPane>
</HBox>
```